# Is the following a GUID

Tags: guid

Is the following a valid GUID?
202008210743518

Comment: Would a better question be: How do I generate a GUID?

Comment: More info (and explanation of format) here: [Online GUID generator](http://www.onlineguidgenerator.com)

Comment: It match the constraints for some sort of timestamp: 2020/08/21 07:43:51(,8?)

Comment: -1. Why cant u do a simple reading on guid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A guid is just a 128 bit number, so sure you could *interpret* it as a guid, just with a lot of 0 padding. They are more commonly expressed as a 32 character hex string though.

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-B7B9B3A4A0DE
```

(which is your seemingly-decimal number expressed in a 32-bit hex string)

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not.  A GUID is 32 hex digits, typically written in groups of 8-4-4-4-12 digits.

Answer (score 3):

A GUID is a Globally Unique Identifier. Typically these are identifiers that combine a number of different factors, such as the current time, plus some ranom component, so that they are very likely to be unique, but this is not guaranteed!

You can create GUIDs using your own mechanism if you like, however, most people use the [Universal Unique Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) standard, which when written in Hex looks like this:

```
21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D
```

If the number you give is supposed to be a GUID, it might work OK, but I would be a bit suspicious as to just how unique it is!

Answer (score 0):

A GUID looks like this: {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier.